# How do I share my internal hard drive?

Tags: file-sharing

I have installed ubuntu on a 3 TB internal hard drive. I want to use it as a server. How do I share the entire internal hard drive on my network?

Comment: as a note, sharing your entire hard drive, including OS files, is a bad idea security-wise.  Anyone with write access to the share would be able to wreck your computer, either accidentally or intentionally.

Answer (score 9):

### Create a Samba share with Nautilus

This is probably the easiest way.

[image: Create a samba share with nautilus]

1. In nautilus **right click on the hard drive** in question
2. In the resulting context menu click **Properties**
3. There select the tab **Share**
4. Check the box **Share this folder**
5. Optionally you can check any of the other boxes
6. Click **Create Share**

The first time you do this, you will be asked if you want to install samba. Your password will be needed to do so. And on a more general note: This is very basic. Next time, try a google search.

There are **other methods** such as **creating an FTP server** or using **ssh and sftp**. I will be happy to go into details on those if you request it in a comment.

Comment: Works with Dolphin in KDE too.

Comment: Can't connect to it though. How do you recommend to connect to it when you always get timeout or no message at all?

Comment: You're missing an important step: As described in official documentation you need to add a user to connectable users - so run `sudo  smbpasswd -a username` where username is a username on the computer you want to share. Enter a password, and then you can use username and password to connect from another device. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

Comment: Requires the package nautilus-share and its dependencies.